# SATA Backward compatibility?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, compatibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I connect a SATA-II hard drive to a SATA-I connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/52001/can-i-connect-a-sata-ii-hard-drive-to-a-sata-i-connection)

Hello everyone

One of my system is really old, but I still use it, right now, the HDD is and old IDE drive that is starting to fail (I got to many damaged sectors) and I'm planing to replace it. The motherboard supports Serial ATA 1 and I have a real nice offer on a SATA 2 drive, can I use that drive on a SATA 1 interface (obviously with reduced speed) just like a USB 2.0 device on a 1.0 port?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question has been asked before; please search for duplicates before asking a question.  any of these posts should answer your question: http://superuser.com/questions/52001/can-i-connect-a-sata-ii-hard-drive-to-a-sata-i-connection .. http://superuser.com/questions/14790/whats-the-difference-between-sata-and-sata-ii-3-0gb

Comment: Thanks could't find that, next time will use "site:superuser.com ***" on google.

Comment: yeah, the search function takes some getting used to.  see http://superuser.com/search for tips; use `intitle:1` to restrict the search to titles; double-quote for exact matches (search on `foo` is fuzzy; search on `"foo"` is exact).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will indeed work fine.

As you said, the drive will run at a lower speed.  It will run at a performance level of 1.5Gb/s compared to the 3.0Gb/s that you would normally achieve with a SATA 2 drive.

Answer (score 1):

As Kez said, this will work fine. However, some drives require you to set jumper settings so that the drive operates in SATAI mode. (Newer drives may do this automatically, not sure.)

Comment: depends on the drive, mostly, but generally i've found drives don't really auto-detect.  see for example http://superuser.com/questions/96085/seagate-7200-12-not-recognized-by-system/96098#96098

Comment: Thanks, will take this into consideration however what I wanted to be sure that i can be achieved before buying a new disc (I already have 3 on the main computer, so buying that and not being able to run in on the old computer would be a wast money) I think i will be able to handle that, if not, you'll see my question here =)

Comment: @fladur - you can always add a SATA-II expansion card if you have an available PCI/PCIe slot.

Comment: Will I get better speeds that SATA on a PCI slot?